# What is causing this error in my piecewise function in R?

Tags: r, function, vector, piecewise

I'm trying to make a piecewise function in R with the following arguments:

```
##### Rules ####

# If x from 2 to 6, x2
# If x < 2, x-5
# If x > 6, x^9
```

Thus, I have made this function to try to fit these arguments:

```
piecewise <- function(x){
  return(ifelse(x < 2, x - 5,
                ifelse(x > 6, x^9, x^2)))
}
```

I created a vector to test this out and fit it into the function:

```
x <- c(1,20,5,2,30)
piecewise(x)
```

However, it gives me the following odd output:

```
[1] -4.0000e+00  5.1200e+11  2.5000e+01  4.0000e+00  1.9683e+13
```

What is causing this issue and how do I fix it?

Comment: Looks right to me, what seems "odd" about it to you?

Comment: Maybe you're unfamiliar with [`e` notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)? R (and many other programs) use `e` for scientific notation, so `5.12e+11` means `5.12 * 10^11`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I think the issue I have is why its in scientific notation in the first place. Is there a quick fix to where it just gives me integers?

Comment: For printing you can use e.g. `sprintf("%.0f", piecewise(x))` (or perhaps `sprintf("%g", piecewise(x))`). Please note that this is only for display purposes.

Comment: 20^9 is a very big number. so must be i scientific notation

Comment: That makes sense. The comments and the answer are informative, so thank you all for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change R's print options for scientific notation by setting the `scipen` "scientific notation penalty" option. Numbers with fewer digits than `scipen` will be printed without scientific notation:

```
options(scipen = 35)
x <- c(1,20,5,2,30)
piecewise(x)
# [1]             -4   512000000000             25              4 19683000000000
```

See `?options` for more details.

Comment: Thank you. I think that worked pretty quickly for what I needed.